# Javascript elements in Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginer in bootstrap. I have tried elements like navbar, dropdowns, modal, carousel etc. and none of them are working properly. I'm guessing, it is because of the JS files which are linked to it. Please help I require these elements for a project.

Thank you.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="conatiner-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbarLogo">MyWebsite</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbar-collapse1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Connect<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script scr="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have any error on your console ?

Comment: There are no errors in the console

Comment: Is the bootstrap.min.js file loading in page? Check in browser dev tools network

Comment: you have src spelt as scr in your script tag, bootstrap probably isn't even loading... plus you should put scripts in the head

Answer (score 1):

<s>this works fine</s> you have a few issues, most are typos as pointed out by @Rachel Gallen but you are also setting the id for navbar-collapse1 to its css selector value. you should set it to id="navbar-collapse1", adding the # is only used when doing a document query for the element. please review this documentation for more on selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
<html>
<body>

<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbarLogo">MyWebsite</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Connect<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div class="conatiner-fluid">? never heard of that one

Comment: :) me either. i just cut and paste his div. updated answer with correctly spelled.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8aLg2ewe/ here's a fiddle of what you just posted. I don't see any toggling/dropdowns happening!

Comment: thats strange because the connect dropdown on your fiddle works fine for me.

Comment: oh yeah, i just widened my screen, and saw that. I had it mobile size, when just the burger menu was visible. The burger doesn't work.

Comment: it was because he was setting his ID to '#navbar-collapse1'. updated the answer, hamburger works now

Comment: I have changed it to 'src' and dropdowns and carousel are working properly. But hamburger menu isn't working.

Comment: After changing data-target="navbar-collapse1" inside <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse1">. It is working.